# Calculate vertex distances of a mesh

Tags: python, numpy, mesh

I am using Numpy arrays to express a triangular mesh.

I have two matrices: `coordinates` is a 3 x n matrix, and `connectivity` is an n x n matrix that uses 0s and 1s to store vertex connectivity.

Now I want to calculate a n x n matrix named `distances` that stores vertex distances. Only the positions where `connectivity[i,j] == 1` are calculated. Anywhere else are not.

What is the most elegant way to calculate this in Python?

For example, I have a mesh of 4 vertices like this:

[image]

Then

```
import numpy as np

coordinates = np.array(
    [
        [-1, -1, 0],    # A
        [1, -1, 0],     # B
        [1, 1, 0],      # C
        [-1, 1, 0]      # D
    ], 
    dtype=np.float32
)

connectivity = np.array(
    [
        [0, 1, 1, 1],    # A-B, A-C, A-D
        [1, 0, 1, 0],    # B-A, B-C
        [1, 1, 0, 1],    # C-A, C-B, C-D
        [1, 0, 1, 0],    # D-A, D-C
    ],
    dtype=np.int32
)

# For this example, expected `distances` is like this
distances = np.array(
    [
        [0, 2, 2.828, 2],   # A-B, A-C, A-D
        [2, 0, 2, 0],       # B-A, B-C
        [2.828, 2, 0, 2],   # C-A, C-B, C-D
        [2, 0, 2, 0],       # D-A, D-C
    ],
    dtype=np.float32
)
```

Comment: post a testable matrices and expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest OK, I have added an example.

Comment: ok, why `A-C` should result to `2.828` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest A-B distance and B-C distance are 2, so A-C distance is sqrt(2*2 + 2*2)=2.828

Comment: so `C-A` also should be `2.828`, but you have `2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute distance between coordinates with [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html)
and ensure it with `connectivity` array at the end:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

dist = cdist(coordinates, coordinates, 'euclidean') * connectivity
print(dist)
```

---

```
[[0.         2.         2.82842712 2.        ]
 [2.         0.         2.         0.        ]
 [2.82842712 2.         0.         2.        ]
 [2.         0.         2.         0.        ]]
```

Comment: This is convenient. Though it may be O(n^2)?

Comment: @landings it internally uses `numpy.linalg.norm` (https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.10.1/scipy/spatial/distance.py#L484)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `np.tile` to efficiently generate all pairs of distances, which are then masked out by the connectivity matrix.

The idea is to generate two matrices containing the tiled vertex coordinates, in the following pattern:

```py
ABCD 
ABCD
ABCD
ABCD
```

and

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
```

The difference of those two matrices then gives you all combinations. If you only want the entries that actually are connected, then you can simply multiply these matrices by the connectivity matrix.

```py
mat = np.tile(coordinates, (4,1,1)) * connectivity[..., None]
mat_t = np.transpose(mat, axes=(1,0,2))

distances = np.sqrt(((mat - mat_t)**2).sum(axis=2))
```

Which gives you the expected result:

```py
array([[0.      , 2.      , 2.828427, 2.      ],
       [2.      , 0.      , 2.      , 0.      ],
       [2.828427, 2.      , 0.      , 2.      ],
       [2.      , 0.      , 2.      , 0.      ]], dtype=float32)
```

Alternatively, assuming you generated the connectivity matrix from a triangle index array, you could use it to generate the distances, and then generate the matrix in a similar fashion as you generate the connectivity matrix.